# How to perform this query in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails active record query which returns a count of the the number of items in each category. In the form

```
Category.joins(:item).group("category_id").count
=> {1=>1, 2=>3}
```

which gives the correct result. I'm having an issue including the category name in the result along with item count. How do I include category name eg.

```
 1, Severe => 1, 
 2, Minor => 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
Category.joins(:item).group([:category_id, :category_name]).count
```

Then you would get something like below:

```
{[1, "Severe"]=>1, [2, "Minor"]=>3}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
Category.joins(:item).group("categories.name").count
```